# How to use Arrayformula to calculate the average with a double condition

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SudAFCawEWHmLMo3WXwhH_t9P-ju3th_UI_5uliko30/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a list of names with a "score" and a code column.
I would like to calculate the average of the scores for each name divided by code. I would like to do it using Arrayformula

I have tried the following formula but it doesn't expand:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,G2:G,C:C,"Z1")/COUNTIF(FILTER(A:C,A:A=G2,C:C="Z1"),G2:G))
```

I think it's because of SUMIFS but I couldn't find any way to replace it.

Thank you

Aresvik solution works well but I would like to calculate the average only if the scores are typed in. currently, the formula counts also the empty cells.
I tried the following formula but it didn't work

```
=ArrayFormula(if(G2:G<>"",iferror(SUMIF(A2:A&C2:C,G2:G&H$1,B2:B)/COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C&B:B,G2:G&H$16">0"),),))
```

Comment: Try the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in cell H2:

`=ArrayFormula(if(G2:G<>"",iferror(SUMIF(A2:A&C2:C,G2:G&H$1,B2:B)/COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C,G2:G&H$1,B2:B,"<>"),),))`

and this in cell I2:

`=ArrayFormula(if(G2:G<>"",iferror(SUMIF(A2:A&C2:C,G2:G&I$1,B2:B)/COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C,G2:G&I$1,B2:B,"<>"),),))`

`SUMIFS` isn't compatible with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

[image]

[image]